# Repackage failed creating uber jar with spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to run create an uber jar to create a docker image of that. I am using spring-boot-maven-plugin to create the uber jar.

My pom file looks like this :

```
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <mainClass>MainClassName</mainClass>
               <layout>JAR</layout>
               <finalName>JARName</finalName>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
                <execution>
                      <goals>
                           <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Command to run : mvn clean package

> Error : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project projectName: Execution default of goal o
>   rg.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file, got C:\GIT\projectLocation\target\classes ->

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source must refer to an existing
> file, got C:\YourPath\YourProject\target\classes

You need to know the following:

With **source file the plugin refers to the original war or jar file** which should be repackaged. The position should be

```
YourPath\YourProject\target
```

So every reason why the war file is not in the specified path can lead to this error:

- the folder is empty (call mvn clean install)
- the location is different (in the pom.xml file it is possible to redefine all directories)
- there is no war file generated in the first place (check pom.xml and its war/jar plugins etc)
- In my case I called the plugin inside a maven `profile`. Part of this profile definition was an overwritten `<artifact.classifier>`:

  ```
  <properties>
    <artifact.classifier>someChangedArtifactName</artifact.classifier>
  </properties>
  ```

  So the resulting file was not `project-name-version.war` but `project-name-version-artifact.classifier.war` so the subsequent call of the spring-maven-plugin couldn't find it